# Reset an elements 'odd' or 'even' status?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tablesorter

I have a table with 'zebra stripes' which adds a class to every second, or 'even', `<tr>`, eg:

```
 $("#summarytable tr:even").addClass("even");
```

I am also using the [Table Sorter](http://tablesorter.com/) plugin which allows the sorting columns alphabetically and numerically if a `<th>` is clicked.

The problem is that 'even' `<tr>`s remain 'even' even after they've been sorted by the plugin and their order shuffled. So, even if I remove and then add the '.even' class again, eg:

```
$("#summarytable th").click(function() {
    $("#summarytable tr").removeClass("even");
    $("#summarytable tr:even").addClass("even");
});
```

It still appears out of order.

Is there someway to 'reset' the order of elements in the DOM and thus reset an elements 'odd' or 'even' status?

Dev example here: http://ryanturner.com.au/tipping/index.php?id=4

Comment: Why on the click event? Are you sure the re-evening is happening AFTER the sorting?

Comment: If you can use CSS3 you may not need any javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the striping is only for styling, you can sidestep this whole problem just using CSS.

[Example:](http://jsfiddle.net/Bmcg4/)

```
tr:nth-child(2n) {
    background: gray;
}
tr:nth-child(2n+1) {
    background: lightgray;
}
```

If you really need some function to run after sorting takes place, a quick glance at [the documentation](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-triggers.html) suggests that you might do it like this:

```
$("table").bind("sortEnd", function() { 
    // ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using jQuery for something that's easily achievable with CSS?

```css
#summarytable tr:nth-child(even) {
    /* your styles here */
}
```

This will update automatically, no matter what happens. Even if the user decides to go into the DOM Inspector and start deleting table rows from the DOM, they will *still* update automatically and look beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Coming from Table Sorter docs, there is a module called Zebra, which adds the relevant classes. You use it like this:

```
$("table").tablesorter({
  widgets: ["zebra"],
  // change the default striping class names
  widgetOptions : {
    zebra : [ "normal-row", "alt-row" ]
  }
});
```